Why is tar not extracting to the specified directory?
In my terminal, I am currently working in ~/tmp/testwiki, which contains the archive testwiki.tgz.
When I run tar -xvf testwiki.tgz data/attic/ data/media/ data/media_attic/ data/media_meta/ data/meta/ data/pages/ -C ./storage, I expect this to extract the specified directories from the tar archive and place them in ~/tmp/testwiki/storage, so I'd get:
~/tmp/testwiki/storage/data/attic
~/tmp/testwiki/storage/data/media
~/tmp/testwiki/storage/data/media_attic
...

...and so on.
However, when I run that command, instead, the contents are extracted to ~/tmp/testwiki/:
~/tmp/testwiki/data/attic
~/tmp/testwiki/data/media
~/tmp/testwiki/data/media-attic
...

I have tried the following values for the -C argument:

storage/
storage
~/tmp/testwiki/storage/
./storage/
./storage

All have the same result: they extract to the working directory instead of ~/tmp/testwiki/storage.
I wish to extract the specified directories and place them in a designated location. What am I missing about how to do this via CLI?
Thank you.

IIRC the order of arguments matters. A -C xyz option must precede the items that are to be extracted into it (so you can have -C loc1 item1 item2 -C loc2 item3 ... to extract different things to different places)
